# Automatic discount code application during checkout in shopify store

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-app, polaris

I am developing a shopify widget to generate discount coupon codes. I want them to be automatically applied when a user generates it, and goes to checkout his cart.
I found out that discount codes can be passed into the URL to be applied automatically, but couldn't find a way to edit the checkout url through my shopify widget.
How can I achieve this?
I am using NodeJS and Polaris
Thank you